# How to deal with frequent spam posts?

Tags: discussion

Recently, some new users have been flooding the site with low quality non-research level posts. Today, I noticed a malicious behavior where a user asks a question and seconds later another new user answer the question.

> What is the policy of StackExchange on spam posts? How should we deal with users that intentionally post many off-topic posts?

Comment: Some of those users: Vaishnavi Sahu and RANJITHA SHET.

Comment: I posted a question on MSO http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278887/153230

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the policy of StackExchange on spam posts?

They should be flagged as spam, as described in [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032) A post that gets 6 spam flags from ordinary users, or 1 spam flag from a moderator, is deleted, locked, "censored" (hidden even from 10K users, unless they look at revision history), and most importantly, the author is blocked from posting again.

It's important to keep in mind the Stack Exchange definition of spam: an advertisement/promotion of some sort, as elaborated in the linked post. A "low quality non-research question" is not spam.

> How should we deal with users that intentionally post many off-topic posts?

Close *and* downvote their posts. They will be either blocked or at least slowed down by the system: [Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460)

Comment: I think there should be a separate flag from advertising spams for these kind of spam posts. Spam is defined more generally as "irrelevant or inappropriate messages", not just advertisement spam.

Comment: On [Meta.se], Gilles suggested flagging them as `low quality`.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2944/5038, flag it for moderator attention, and downvote.  Use a custom flag, and explain what's going on; the moderators have tools to deal with this.

Plagiarism violates SE rules.  The moderators can take action.  See my answer to that other question for details.

Comment: I think we need a more systematic solution. It is a waste of everyone's time to deal with these manually.

Comment: Completely agree with @Kaveh. I ran out of flags today.