# How to signal users that probably are bots?

Tags: discussion

In the last hours some users:

Harsh Vardhan Rai, Ria Muglihal, Vishesh Sinha

are copying questions and answers from other users.
Probably they are bots ?!?

I flagged some of the questions/answers for moderator attention, but is there a more effective way to signal those suspect behaviours (or even temporarily disable those users)?

Comment: I guess for now the best solution is flagging those answers. Our moderators need to be more aggressive against those users. All thanks to Reyzin since he is active in chasing those abusive accounts. Certainly,  he needs more help from others mods :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention.  The moderators have tools to deal with this.  Use a custom flag, and explain what's going on.

TCS.SE is under attack by a voting ring who are upvoting each others questions and answers.  They started at CS.SE, and we've been destroying them left and right over there.  They're still trying at CS.SE and now they're also trying to attack Stack Overflow and TCS.SE.  Only the moderators can take action, but we can help them by identifying the problematic users.

You can downvote while you're at it, if you like.

See also my answer on CS.SE about what users can do:  https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1258/755.

Comment: OK, thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the flags -- they are very helpful.  Please keep them coming.  Starting now, I am aggressively destroying the spam accounts, all of their content, and all of the reputation associated with their votes.

Comment: I would like to second Lev's thanks for the flags and the vigilance of the community.

Comment: I consumed all my available flags ... I'll continue with "signal as spam" if I see other posts.